# Testing Batch class called from class implementing Schedulable interface

Tags: apex

I have below class

```
global class OpportunityReminderSchedule implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
{
    try{
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                                 FROM CronTrigger 
                                 WHERE 
                                 Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

        system.debug('--cron expression--'+ct.CronExpression);
        system.debug('-cron trigger run--'+ ct.TimesTriggered);

        OpportunityReminderMail orm = new OpportunityReminderMail();
        orm.sendMail();

        OppReminderBatchSMS orbs = new OppReminderBatchSMS();

        integer scopeSize = 100;

        Database.executeBatch(orbs, scopeSize);

        //cleaning(); // to clean deleted or aborted schedule jobs.

    }catch(exception ex){
        system.debug('--Exception is--'+ ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have written the below test class:

```
@isTest
private class TestOpportunityReminderSchedule {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
   test.startTest();
   OpportunityReminderSchedule ors = new OpportunityReminderSchedule();
   String schedule = '0 0 23 * * ?';
   system.schedule('Daily Schedule' , schedule, ors);

   OppReminderBatchSMS orbs = new OppReminderBatchSMS();
   id batchProcessID = Database.executeBatch(orbs);
   test.stopTest();
}

static testMethod void myUnitTest2() {

    list<Opportunity> tempOpp = new list<Opportunity>();
    list<smagicinteract__smsMagic__c> smsObjectList = new list<smagicinteract__smsMagic__c>();

    User u = [Select id
                 from
                 User
                 where
                 name='Balamurugan Nadar'];
    system.runAs(u){
        try{
            Profile p = [select id 
                                from 
                                Profile 
                                where 
                                name='BMCC system Admin SSO']; 

            User bdeUser = new user(alias = 'test123', email='test123@noemail.com',related_team__c = 'BDE', 
                                emailencodingkey='UTF-8', firstName='Nahush', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                                localesidkey='en_IN', profileid = p.Id, country='India',
                                timezonesidkey='Asia/Kolkata', username='test_g@noemail.com'); 
            insert bdeUser; 


            Account newAccount = new Account();
            newAccount.Name = 'testAccount';
            insert newAccount;

           Contact newContact = new Contact();
           newContact.LastName = 'testContactName';
           newContact.AccountId = newAccount.id;
           newContact.Email = 'rohit.k@bmcgroup.in';
           newContact.ccEmail__c ='testCCEmail@bmcgroup.in';
           insert newContact;
           system.Debug('---Contact ID---'+ newContact.id);
            system.Debug('---Contact ID---'+ newContact.id);

            RecordType rec = [Select Id, DeveloperName 
                                             From 
                                             RecordType 
                                             where 
                                             SObjectType = 'Opportunity'
                                             AND
                                             Name ='Private'];                                                 


            for(integer i=0; i<200; i++){
                Opportunity scheduledOpp = new Opportunity();
                scheduledOpp.Name = 'testOpp';
                scheduledOpp.AccountId = newAccount.id;
                scheduledOpp.Enquiry_For__c = 'Pvt. Ltd. Registration';
                scheduledOpp.StageName = 'Negotiation';
                scheduledOpp.CloseDate = system.today();
                scheduledOpp.underTest__c = TRUE;
                scheduledOpp.OwnerId = bdeUser.id;
                scheduledOpp.recordTypeId = rec.id;
                scheduledOpp.contact__c = newContact.id;
                scheduledOpp.client_interest__c = 'Relevant';
                scheduledOpp.First_Follow_Up_Date__c = system.today();

                tempOpp.add(scheduledOpp);
            }

            insert tempOpp;

            test.startTest();

            OppReminderBatchSMS orbs = new OppReminderBatchSMS();
            id batchProcessID = Database.executeBatch(orbs);

            test.stopTest();
        }catch(exception e){

        }
    }               
}
```

}

Why still this below part is not covered through my test class.

```
OppReminderBatchSMS orbs = new OppReminderBatchSMS();

   integer scopeSize = 100;

   Database.executeBatch(orbs, scopeSize);
```

Any help regarding this as previously it was covered but after salesforce annual update it is now getting covered ( it is what I think) as there might be some changes. 
Kindly help

Comment: Your first testmethod is trying to do two Database.executeBatch - one in the schedulable class and the second in the testmethod itself. Only one executeBatch() will execute per test method.  Normally, one writes one testmethod to do code coverage/functionality on the schedulable class and a second testmethod that tests the batchable class without trying to schedule it

Comment: @crop1645 I tried what you are saying. But nothing happen. Execute batch is not getting tested. I am trying other things. I will let you know when I find something. Thanks anyways.